# Referencing DOM within object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table where each row contains some data (`data-id`) and a `<div class = "upload">Upload</div>`.  The uploader needs to be passed an object which contains `uploader_obj.button` set as the initiating `<div>`, any parameters such as data-id to be sent to the server, and a bunch of other stuff which I didn't show.

The following script loops over the table, modifies the object to set button and params.id, and creates the uploader on each row.

While a separate upload button is created on each row, they each reference the same params.id which is set to the last row's value (i.e. 222).  I need each to be set to the value of their specific row.

One way to fix it is to have each uploader have it's own upload_obj, but this seems like a waste of memory.

Instead, I tried to reference data-id within the uploader_obj.  I can do so within onSubmit, however, haven't figured out how to use this value to set param.id.  I've tried to set it within param by doing something like `params: {'id':$(this.button).parent().parent().data('id')}` but this is my document, and not the uploader.

So...  Without making a separate uploader_obj for each row, how could I make each row's uploader sent its own param.id to the server?  Thank you

PS.  Sorry for the weak title.  I really tried to think of a better one but couldn't.

```
<table>
    <tr data-id="123"><td>Hello</td><td><div class="upload">Upload</div></td></tr>
    <tr data-id="321"><td>Hello</td><td><div class="upload">Upload</div></td></tr>
    <tr data-id="222"><td>Hello</td><td><div class="upload">Upload</div></td></tr>
</table>

var uploader_obj = {
  button:null,
  params: {'id':null},
  onSubmit: function(id, fileName) {
     var id=$(this.button).parent().parent().data('id')
     console.log(id);
  },
  otherStuff: whatever
};


$('#myTable div.upload').each(function(i,v){
    uploader_obj.button=this;
    uploader_obj.params.id=$(this).parent().parent().data('id');
    new qq.FileUploaderBasic(uploader_obj);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the same object in every iteration, just create the object from the values you have inside the loop instead:

```
$('#myTable div.upload').each(function(i,ele){
    new qq.FileUploaderBasic({
        button: ele,
        params: {
            id: $(ele).closest('tr').data('id')
        },
        onSubmit: function(id, fileName) {
            var id=$(this).closest('tr').data('id')
        },
        otherStuff: whatever
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is probably what I will need to do.  The object passed to FireUploaderBasic is bigger than I showed, and I hoped there was a way they can be passed the same object.

Comment: If you want different values, you'll need different objects, or at least rewrite all the values in the object which in your case looks like it's more work than just creating a new one on every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you never create a new object of "uploader_obj". So on every loop-iteration you are overwriting the values of your object.

edit:

```
var a = new Object();

$('#myTable div.upload').each(function(i,v){
    a[i] = uploader_obj;
    a[i].button=this;
    a[i].params.id=$(this).parent().parent().data('id');
    new qq.FileUploaderBasic(a[i]); 
});
```

Comment: Agree.  So is creating a new object for each row the only solution?

Comment: And how would I create a new object for each row?  I tried `new qq.FileUploaderBasic($(uploader_obj).clone());` with no success.

Comment: I see you changed the name to an array (or is it an object?)  Regardless, I see why you are doing it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making uploader object as a global variable, if you make it local varaible to qq.FileUploaderBasic function and send button_object and data_id as a parameter, may be it will work.
you can try like

```
$('#myTable div.upload').each(function(i,v){
    var button=this;
    var id=$(this).parent().parent().data('id');
    new qq.FileUploaderBasic(button,id);
});
```

and keep your object inside your function.

Comment: This would require modifying qq.FileUploaderBasic more than I wish to do.